# How to insert text exactly after progressbar

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I have a jquery progress bar, i need to insert some text after progress bar.
But text comes under the progress bar. Please let me know how to solve this.
I have tried using:

```
<div id="progressbar" style="width:150px;height:25px;"></div><div>Lesson 2</div>
```

Comment: `float` both to `left` OR make both `display: inline-block`

Comment: Research the `float` and `display` CSS attributes.

Comment: Please provide some more code, or a live demo of your problem. The problem seems to be that the progress bar is a block element, but to fix this, I'd need to know what the context is, to know what would be the best approach to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block`

HTML:

```
<div id="progressbar" style="width:150px;height:25px;"></div>
<div id="text">Lesson2</div>
```

CSS:

```
#progressbar{
    background-color:red;
    display: inline-block;
}
#text{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhxj8/)

Comment: If i use like your answer i am getting Lesson2 on the Progressbar not beside the progressbar..i am using jquery progressbar for "progressbar" to design progress.